# Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to remove the item from the localstorage json data. but have error in my console 'splice' undefined. Please Help Me..

**This is my Controller**

```
app.controller('favgame', function($scope, $localStorage){
    $scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('favgame');
    var favgames = JSON.parse($scope.saved);
    $scope.onItemDelete = function(index) {
      $scope.favgames.splice(favgames[index],1);
    };
});
```

**This is my ng-click code**

```
<ion-delete-button class="button button-clear ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemDelete($index)">
</ion-delete-button>
```

Thank You!

Comment: You need to pass the index inside splice method. favgames[index] does not mean anything.

Comment: `$scope.favgames` doesn't appear to exist, you defined it as `var`

Comment: `splice(favgames[index],1)` doesn't make sense and `$scope.favgames` is never defined. This should have been trivial to at least see it's the wrong variable with simple console debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect splice, instead use below. `$scope.favgames`, doesn't contain any values and is undefined.

```
favgames.splice(index,1);
```

Or set,

```
$scope.favgames = favgames.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: Hi friend, it's not working for me.. After changes Now my controller is.. `$scope.favgames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favgame'));
    $scope.onItemDelete = function(index) {
      $scope.favgames.splice(index,1);
    };`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line:

```
var favgames = JSON.parse($scope.saved);
```

with this one:

```
$scope.favgames = JSON.parse($scope.saved);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `var favgames` to var `$scope.favgames`